# Adding a boat to the Gazebo environment

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, surface, gazebo-simu

I want to work on a surface vehicle in the gazebo environment. I've looked at various resources on this topic, but haven't been able to find a working example file for the system I'm using. In the sources I found, the vehicle sinks into the water. I also did research to get it on the water, but I couldn't get any results. My system information is as follows. Is there a source for my system information where I can work on the surface vehicle? Or do I need to change the version?

System info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS Noetic Distribution
- Gazebo 11

I added ocean and boat model to Gazebo environment. To keep the boat afloat, I looked at this resource:

https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=hydrodynamics&cat=physics

I added the codes in this resource to the boat.sdf file. But the boat did not rise above the water.

Comment: could you mimic that behavior by adding a force opposed to gravity instead? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I was working on drones. Now I want to work on surface vehicles. In general, my aim is to control the surface vehicle in the gazebo environment, Image processing, Lidar, Autonomous movement etc. work on issues. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do what you said. Can you cite the source? Also, when I installed my system on Ubuntu 18.04 and used the Melodic distribution, I could not get any results.